# Function to replace values in pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas, function

The problem: I have several hundred columns needing value recoding.
Why: Need to create a large value equating to missing/refused that is clearly discernible from other values in the column

The example below is the code I've used to change the value of C2FDF1 from 8 to 999 and 9 to 997.

```
df.loc[df['C2DF1'] == 9, 'C2DF1'] = 997
df.loc[df['C2DF1'] == 8, 'C2DF1'] = 999
```

The task: I'd like a def function that I could use that recodes values conditional on its current value. I'm thinking a function with if elif.

This is what I've tried: (I made it elif >5 so it'd capture all values between 5.1 and 8.9)

```
def recode (dataframe, column):
  if dataframe[column] == 9:
    return dataframe[column] == 997
  elif dataframe[column] > 5:
    return dataframe[column] == 999
  else:
    return 'column recoded'

recode(dfcols, 'C2DF1')
```

Thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: Have you tried adding two new parameters called **old_value** and **new value** to your function?

Comment: Are you familiar with the apply method? You can write a custom function that takes an integer and changes it per your specifications.

Comment: StonedTensor tell me more! I have not done that.